# Use non-commited values in SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, commit

In some function (simplified here), I have something like this :

```
public void transfertOrganisms(Organism firstOrganism, Organism secondOrganism){

  firstOrganism.setMetaExercice(DaoHelper.getMaxMetaExercieId("organisme") + 1);
  HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(firstOrganism);

  secondOrganism.setMetaExercice(DaoHelper.getMaxMetaExercieId("organisme") + 1);
  HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(secondOrganism);
}
```

In the DaoHelper.java

```
public static int getMaxMetaExercieId(String tableName) {
    Query query;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT MAX(META_EXERCICE_ID) FROM " + tableName);
    Integer max = (Integer) query.uniqueResult();
    tx.commit();
    if (max == null)
      return 0;
    return max;
}
```

Now, since the transaction is not committed yet, `DaoHelper.getMaxMetaExercieId("organisme")` will always return the same value. Without having to manage myself the currentMax (like making a global variable or something), is there a way to use the non-committed values of the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't only have a problem with the id for these rows within this transaction if other transactions that update the Organism table can execute at the same time (for example, if there are other users of the application creating Organism rows concurrently). I've used two solutions for this: use an "auto incrementing" column (`auto_increment` in MySQL and MSSQL); or create a table that holds the maximum value, and update the value in that table in a separate transaction.